# Dual boot installation problem in HP

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 in my friend's HP laptop where windows has been already installed. I inserted the Live USB and restarted the laptop. Then I tried to install Ubuntu but the installation process didn't found any OS(but there was windows 10). And when I chose `something else` option I noticed that it showed full hard-disk as `free space` (but there were 5 partitions and those were accessed in GUI). For this inconsistent situation I quit the installation.

Can anybody help me?

**Edit**

[image]

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x9daac03c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      718847      358400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          718848   274434047   136857600    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       274434048   694204415   209885184    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       694204416  1953521663   629658624    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       694206464  1113976831   209885184    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6      1113978880  1533749247   209885184    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7      1533751296  1953521663   209885184    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.8

Caution: invalid backup GPT header, but valid main header; regenerating
backup header from main header.

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged

Found valid MBR and corrupt GPT. Which do you want to use? (Using the
GPT MAY permit recovery of GPT data.)
 1 - MBR
 2 - GPT
 3 - Create blank GPT

Your answer: 1
Disk /dev/sda: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 2D49C476-E1D2-48FB-A46D-85D99282AAA8
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 11629 sectors (5.7 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048          718847   350.0 MiB   0700  Microsoft basic data
   2          718848       274434047   130.5 GiB   0700  Microsoft basic data
   3       274434048       694204415   200.2 GiB   0700  Microsoft basic data
   5       694206464      1113976831   200.2 GiB   0700  Microsoft basic data
   6      1113978880      1533749247   200.2 GiB   0700  Microsoft basic data
   7      1533751296      1953521663   200.2 GiB   0700  Microsoft basic data

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fixparts /dev/sda
FixParts 0.8.8

Loading MBR data from /dev/sda

NOTICE: GPT signatures detected on the disk, but no 0xEE protective partition!
The GPT signatures are probably left over from a previous partition table.
Do you want to delete them (if you answer 'Y', this will happen
immediately)? (Y/N):
```

Boot repair program's output is [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25958419/)

Comment: verify which mode windows boots (legacy or EFI) boot the USB in the same mode

Comment: @ravery windows boots in legacy mode. I also boot USB in legacy but failed.

Comment: is ther an EFI folder on the usb? rename it. to force legacy boot

Comment: yes. a folder named EFI. I will try and response to you. thank you.

Comment: @ravery will I only change the folder name?(it contains /BOOT/BOOTx64.EFI)

Comment: only change the folder name, leave everything inside alone

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61863/discussion-between-banda-muhammad-al-helal-and-ravery).